# Symfony translations:update Entity Annotations

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, entity, translation

I use extracting translation from this article: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-extracting-translation-contents-from-php-files

to extract all translations to csv file.:

```
php bin/console translation:update --force en --output-format csv
```

It works fine to translations e.g.: from Controller but not in entity assert?

Is there any way to do that?

In this article: https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#extracting-translation-contents-and-updating-catalogs-automatically
is written that translations are taken from twig file or php files that use autowire translator service.

I use  Annotations assert in Entites but I can change it for another one, e.g. PHP validations.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: extracting translatable strings in a reliable way is hard, since some assumptions can only be done conservatively. for example that there is code like `$translator->trans('string')`, which already crumbles, when you have code like `$translator->trans('string'.$suffix)` or similar. So, most assumptions fail at some point (necessarily). How the string extraction works: a *loader* determines which files to load (one loader for twig templates, one loader for php files etc) and an extractor then looks into it to create a list of translation keys. You can surely write your own! ;o)

Comment: you might look at https://github.com/php-translation/symfony-bundle it might give you more functionality including extracting from validation annotations.